# PowerShell output random numbers to csv. CSV full of empty lines

Tags: powershell, csv, random

Actually 2 part question here. The code below outputs nothing but 1000 blank lines to the csv. I'm just trying to output a random range of numbers to a csv and I actually need to follow up with 4 more columns of randomly generated numbers like this first attempt so the second part of this is after getting this first issue resolved how would I direct the next ranges to the other columns?

`Get-Random -Count 998 -InputObject (8000..8999) | Export-Csv -Path SingleColumn.csv -NoTypeInformation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.2) same as [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv?view=powershell-7.2) is not designed to deal with array of values:

```
0..10 | ConvertTo-Csv # Outputs `AutomationNull.Value`
```

Both cmdlets require you to feed them objects:

```
0..10 | ForEach-Object { [pscustomobject]@{ foo = $_ } } | ConvertTo-Csv
```

You can create new objects easily with [`PSCustomObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.2).

As for the second question, you can dynamically create a dataset by tweaking this code:

```
$columnsCount = 5
$numberOfrows = 998
$min = 8000; $max = 9000

1..$numberOfrows | ForEach-Object {
    $out = [ordered]@{}
    foreach($column in 1..$columnsCount) {
        $out["Column $column"] = Get-Random -Minimum $min -Maximum $max
    }
    [pscustomobject] $out
} | Export-Csv path/to/csv.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Few lines of Csv output would look something like this:

```
"Column 1","Column 2","Column 3","Column 4","Column 5"
"8314","8937","8789","8946","8267"
"8902","8500","8107","8006","8287"
"8655","8204","8552","8681","8863"
"8643","8375","8891","8476","8475"
"8338","8243","8175","8568","8917"
"8747","8629","8054","8505","8351"
"8102","8859","8564","8018","8817"
"8810","8154","8845","8074","8436"
"8626","8731","8070","8156","8459"
....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class rdot {[int]$num;[datetime]$dtg}
$dts=$(Get-Date).ToString("ddHHmmssMMMMyyyy").ToUpper()
$randoFile=".\$dts"+"_rando.csv"
while ($true){
$row=[rdot]::new()
$row.num=get-random -Maximum 26
$row.dtg=Get-Date
$row|Export-Csv -append $randoFile
Start-Sleep -S 1
}
```

Then may look like this? using gc .\therandofile.csv -tail 137 -wait

```
13","10/19/2023 11:09:27 PM"
"1","10/19/2023 11:09:28 PM"
"3","10/19/2023 11:09:29 PM"
"11","10/19/2023 11:09:30 PM"
"24","10/19/2023 11:09:31 PM"
"22","10/19/2023 11:09:32 PM"
"13","10/19/2023 11:09:33 PM"
"7","10/19/2023 11:09:34 PM"
"2","10/19/2023 11:09:35 PM"
"13","10/19/2023 11:09:36 PM"
"18","10/19/2023 11:09:37 PM"
"3","10/19/2023 11:09:38 PM"
"15","10/19/2023 11:09:39 PM"
"16","10/19/2023 11:09:40 PM"
"19","10/19/2023 11:09:41 PM"
"23","10/19/2023 11:09:42 PM"
"14","10/19/2023 11:09:43 PM"
"1","10/19/2023 11:09:44 PM"
"19","10/19/2023 11:09:45 PM"
"25","10/19/2023 11:09:46 PM"
"6","10/19/2023 11:09:47 PM"
"4","10/19/2023 11:09:48 PM"
"22","10/19/2023 11:09:49 PM"
"20","10/19/2023 11:09:50 PM"
```